# Getting error in .is_valid() method in DRF

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework

I am tyring to create a User Registration API, but I am getting an error when using a POST request in the following view:

```py
@action(methods=['GET', 'POST'], detail=False, permission_classes=[AllowAny])
def users(self, request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        if serializer.available():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The exception returned is the following:

```
Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when 
instantiating the serializer instance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass an object or a queryset to a serializer when you want to serialize it, so it's fine in your GET method.

However, when you want to create an object using a serializer, you have to pass the `data` parameter before calling `.is_valid()`, and only then you can create your new objects with`save()`. This is because the serializer needs to validate the data given to him before he does any save.

What you should do is the following:

```
    [...]
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked thank you man